# How to convert a mysql query into transact SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a query that works in MySQL.  I need to create the same result using TRANSACT SQL.  I've not been able to figure out the incantation.  Here is the MySQL query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempo AS 
(SELECT master, MAX(nev) AS max 
 FROM accounts 
 WHERE where-clause 
 GROUP BY master 
 ORDER BY max DESC LIMIT 3);

SET @min = (SELECT MIN(max) FROM tempo);

SELECT * FROM accounts 
WHERE master IN (SELECT master FROM tempo) AND nev >= @min ORDER BY NEV DESC;
```

Help or pointer to explanation would be appreciated

Comment: MySQL to SQL server conversion is simple with minor changes. But it seems your MySQL query is complicated for simple problem and can be solved without using temporary table, could you post the purpose and expected output of this query, so someone can have simple query in SQL server.

Comment: Are you just trying to allow for ties, where more than 3 records might tie for that same position? Or does one `master` maybe have several `nev` that would fit in the top 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used MySQL, but I'm thinking this is what you want:

```
DECLARE @min INT;

SELECT TOP 3
       master
     , MAX(nev) AS max
INTO #tempo
FROM accounts
WHERE WHERE-clause
GROUP BY master
ORDER BY max DESC;

SELECT @min = MIN(max)
FROM #tempo;

SELECT *
FROM accounts
WHERE master IN
      (
          SELECT master FROM #tempo
      )
      AND nev >= @min
ORDER BY NEV DESC;
```

Comment: @JohnWooten You need to declare all variables used.  I'll update my answer to show it.

Comment: Thanks!  Really fast and absolutely worked with the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT top 3 master, MAX(nev) AS max into #tempo FROM accounts WHERE where-clause GROUP BY master ORDER BY max DESC;

DECLARE @min NUMERIC(38);
SET @min = (SELECT MIN(max) FROM #tempo);

SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE master IN (SELECT master FROM #tempo) AND nev >= @min ORDER BY NEV DESC;
```

I would translate it in this way. But you don't need the temporary. You could write one single query to have your result, it would be better for the SQL Engine.
Hope it helps.

Comment: In a single query:   With tempo AS
(SELECT TOP 3
       master
     , MAX(nev) AS max
INTO #tempo
FROM accounts
WHERE WHERE-clause
GROUP BY master
ORDER BY max DESC
)
,atMin AS (
SELECT  MIN(max) AS mincol
FROM tempo)
SELECT *
FROM accounts
WHERE master IN
      (
          SELECT master FROM tempo
      )
      AND nev >= (select mincol from atMin)
ORDER BY NEV DESC;

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
WITH tempo AS (
    SELECT TOP 3 master, 
        MAX(nev) AS max 
    FROM accounts 
    WHERE [WHERE-clause] 
    GROUP BY master 
    )

SELECT @min = MIN(max)
FROM tempo;

SELECT *
FROM accounts
WHERE master IN (
        SELECT master
        FROM tempo
        )
    AND nev >= @min
ORDER BY NEV DESC;
```

That being said, there are likely better ways to write this (such as one single query in SQL Server), but to each their own.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a CTE as a better option than a temp table, and a `JOIN` will likely be a better substitute for the `IN()` expression, with the same results:

```
WITH temp0 As (
  SELECT TOP 3 master, MAX(nev) AS max 
  FROM accounts 
  WHERE where-clause 
  GROUP BY master 
  ORDER BY MAX(nev) DESC 
)
SELECT a.* 
FROM accounts a 
INNER JOIN temp0 t ON t.master = a.master
WHERE a.nev >= (SELECT MIN(max) FROM temp0) 
ORDER BY a.NEV DESC;
```

This would have been the better way to write it in recent versions of MySql, too.